# How to handle div image click event for every time execution of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
function first(Objs) {
    var imgid= Objs;
    secondMethod(imgid);
    $('#imags_'+imgid.id).one('click', function(e) {
        alert(imgid.id)
    });    
}

function secondmethod(imgid) {
    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.id="imags_"+imgid.id;
    boxText.innerHTML = '<div id="content" >' + '<img src=\"image.png\" width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" id ="\images_id\" />' + '</div>';         
}
```

- I am refreshing (executing) first method every 10 seconds (`Objs.id=1`).
- So its two methods executed every 10 secs,
- Example after 3 refreshes (i.e. executes 3 times), then when I click image I got `imageid` 3 times (i.e. alert output is 1).
- How to get only one output  when I click image with last executed object id.
- Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give the image a class:

```
boxText.innerHTML = '<div id="content" >'+        
    '<img src=\"image.png\" width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" class ="\images_id\" />'+
    '</div>';
```

And use a delegated event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.images_id', function() {
    alert(this.id)
});
```

Also, your example doesn't show it but I assume `boxText` is appended to the DOM at some point?

Comment: thanks for quick replaying..using of this var boxtext i displaying image on map.am refrreshing map every 10 sec with image.image getting on map but when i click i got after 3 refreshings 3 ids i.e alerts getting.i used delegate also.

Comment: and i used `if($('#imags_'+imgid.id).is(':visible')){ }` for avoiding if already visible on map when refreshing.